# How to take items in an index as columns in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas data-frame where the information in the index are headers for each column. This one is tricky because each row has data that the other rows may not have. I am trying to replace those values as None. I use the loc method and separated them by index, but I am concern of mismatch data since certain rows do not have all the data like the others.

```
1. **INDEX**       1.  **INFO**
2. address         2. 123 APPLE STREET
3. phone           555-5555
4. name            APPLE STORE
5. website         APPLE.COM
6. type            BUSINESS
7. address         456 peach ave
8. phone           777-7777
9. name            PEACH STORE
10. website         PEACH.COM
11. type            BUSINESS
12. address         789 banana rd
13. phone           999-9999
14. name            banana store
15. type            BUSINESS
```

I WANT TO CONVERT TO THIS

```
20.  **ADDRESS**      **PHONE**      **NAME**    **WEBSITE**        **TYPE**
21.  123 APPLE ST   555-5555        APPLE STORE     APPLE.COM        BUSINESS
22.  345 PEACH AVE  777-7777        PEACH STORE     PEACH.COM        BUSINESS
23.  789 banana rd  999-9999        banana store    None             BUSINESS
```

This is what I have tried.
Import Pandas as pd

```
address = data.loc['formatted_address']
name = data.loc['name']
phone_number = data.loc['formatted_phone_number']
website = data.loc['website']
field = data.loc['types']
newdf = pd.DataFrame(address['info'])
newdf['Name'] = name['info'].to_list()
newdf['website'] = website['info'].to_list()  # 
print(newdf)
```

When I print the newdf I get this error.
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

It is clearly telling me that one column is not same length as the other and that is because of the website. The length for Name is 20 and website is 19. I am trying to find a way to get that make that missing data as None, so the length will be in even again.

Update: I think it would help to show some of the work I put in to make the Data Frame work. This is a google api that I am trying to adjust for a pandas data frame. The raw data is json and when extracting it, it was easy because I use some if statements and I am good to go. However, I am using a for loop which gives me a list of dictionaries and I couldn't use the dictionary .get method to extract columns. So, I append the key and values of the dictionary and put it to separate list.

```
df1=[]
df2=[]
address= "19.43217, -100.542581"
geocode_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location={}&radius=5000&types=bakery".format(address)
if api_key is not None:
    geocode_url = geocode_url + "&key={}".format(api_key)

    # Ping google for the reuslts:
    results = requests.get(geocode_url)
    # Results will be in JSON format - convert to dict using requests functionality
    places_result = results.json()
#     Ping google for the results:
    for place in places_result['results']:
        my_place_id= place['place_id']
        my_fields= ['name', 'formatted_phone_number','website', 'type','formatted_address']
        place_details= gmaps.place(place_id= my_place_id, fields= my_fields)

#         df1.append(place_details['result'])
#         print(place_details['result'].values())
        for key, value in place_details['result'].items():

            df1.append(key)
            df2.append(value)
data=pd.DataFrame(df2,df1)
data.columns=['info']
data
```

Comment: Edit your post, don't add info in comment

Comment: Seems like a simple pivot or crosstab

Comment: Hey Datanovice. that was my first go was to use a pivot and call it a day. but I got an error saying it was an unhashable list. Which was weird. So I converted it to tuples and I still got the same issue.

Comment: Maybe newdf.T and go from there?

Comment: newdf.T is a nice thought, but remember it only transpose the rows to columns. So I get one big row. BTW, that was second thing I did besides the pivot. :)

Comment: You should structure your data frame correctly when you *create* it. If it's generated via loading from a file, either fix the file structure or load it in a more sensible manner than directly into a data frame. This would avoid the problem entirely.

Comment: Are you ok if i ask a separate question on this topic regarding this questions data, i think i have a solution, but would like to open up my idea as a separate question

Comment: Sure, I have no problem with that.

Comment: @SolomonRichberg  I have an answer to my question based on this that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59023634/how-do-you-combine-like-column-names-into-separate-rows-in-pandas  I'm very interested in this as well, so i hope these extra questions help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a grouping variable, then reshape using `pivot`

```
df.assign(grp=df.iloc[:,0].str.contains('address').cumsum()).pivot('grp','INDEX','INFO')
Out: 
INDEX              address          name     phone      type    website
grp                                                                    
1      2. 123 APPLE STREET   APPLE STORE  555-5555  BUSINESS  APPLE.COM
2            456 peach ave   PEACH STORE  777-7777  BUSINESS  PEACH.COM
3            789 banana rd  banana store  999-9999  BUSINESS        NaN
```

how your df looks like:

```
     INDEX                 INFO
0   address  2. 123 APPLE STREET
1     phone             555-5555
2      name          APPLE STORE
3   website            APPLE.COM
4      type             BUSINESS
5   address        456 peach ave
6     phone             777-7777
7      name          PEACH STORE
8   website            PEACH.COM
9      type             BUSINESS
10  address        789 banana rd
11    phone             999-9999
12     name         banana store
13     type             BUSINESS
```

Comment: Hi Onyambu, thank you for your response. Unfortunately, I am still getting that typeerror. TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: @SolomonRichberg what do you mean by that? where is the error?

Comment: When I use the pivot. For some reason it is treating the dataframe as a list, which pivot tables deem unhashable in pandas. So, it gives that whenever I use a pivot

Answer (score 0):

It is pivoting table. I use `unstack`. As in your comment, I guess your `INDEX` isn't a column. It is the index of the dataframe, so I change the code accordingly.

```
s = df.groupby('INDEX').cumcount()
df_out = df.set_index(s, append=True).INFO.unstack(0, fill_value='None')

Out[111]:
INDEX           address          name     phone      type    website
0      123 APPLE STREET   APPLE STORE  555-5555  BUSINESS  APPLE.COM
1         456 peach ave   PEACH STORE  777-7777  BUSINESS  PEACH.COM
2         789 banana rd  banana store  999-9999  BUSINESS       None
```

---

*Note*: since you want `None`, I fill `NaN` with string `None`. If you want python `None`, you should just leave it as `NaN` because they work same way. If you want `NaN`, take out the option `fill_value='None'`

Comment: Hi Andy, I am working on this script and so far, I feel I am getting close. The cumcount will give me a count for each item in the index. Which makes sense.  However, I am getting  a  KeyError: 'INDEX'. Not sure why?

Comment: you mean `df.groupby('INDEX').cumcount()` works, but `df.set_index([s, 'INDEX'])` gave `KeyError: 'INDEX'` ?

Comment: Correct, that is what I meant Andy

Comment: @SolomonRichberg: `INDEX` is the index or the column of the dataframe? Could you run `df.columns` to see whether the string `INDEX` is in the output?

Comment: This is what it returned. Index(['info'], dtype='object')

Comment: @SolomonRichberg: it means your `INDEX` is the index of `df`. I changed the code to handle it. Check my edited.

Comment: I got an attributerror this time. AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'unstack'

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick,

```
    import pandas as pd

    INDEX = ['address', 'phone', 'name', 'website', 'type', 'address', 'phone', 'name', 'website', 'type', 'address', 'phone', 'name', 'type']
    INFO = ['123 APPLE STREET', '555-5555', 'APPLE STORE', 'APPLE.COM', 'BUSINESS', '456 peach ave', '777-7777', 'PEACH STORE', 'PEACH.COM', 'BUSINESS', '789 banana rd', '999-9999', 'banana store', 'BUSINESS']
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=INDEX, data=INFO, columns=['INFO'])
    df.index.name = 'INDEX'
    df2 = df.groupby('INDEX').agg(INFO=('INFO', list))
    pd.DataFrame(df2['INFO'].to_list(), index=df2.index).transpose()
```

Here's the output you get,

```
    Out[132]: 
    INDEX           address          name     phone      type    website
    0      123 APPLE STREET   APPLE STORE  555-5555  BUSINESS  APPLE.COM
    1         456 peach ave   PEACH STORE  777-7777  BUSINESS  PEACH.COM
    2         789 banana rd  banana store  999-9999  BUSINESS       None
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. The majority of the answers can accomplish this task. however there was a bug in the dataframe. It was still giving me an error of a list no matter what I did, so I did something that was unorthodox in Python. I saved the PDF as an excel sheet and bring it back to a pandas data frame. Once I did that, the traceback disappear. Weird huh? The bigger question is to how to prevent it from happening. But thank you for all your responses.