# How do you combine like column names into separate rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

If I  have the following data, and read it in, I get column names with .1 or .2 for like columns. Here is the data:

```
import io
dfff=io.StringIO("""address,phone,name,website,type,address,phone,name,website,type,address,phone,name,type
123 APPLE STREET,555-5555,APPLE STORE,APPLE.COM,BUSINESS,456 peach ave,777-7777,PEACH STORE,PEACH.COM,BUSINESS,789 banana rd,999-9999,banana store,BUSINESS""")

dfff=io.StringIO("""address,phone,name,website,type,address,phone,name,website,type,address,phone,name,type 
123 APPLE STREET,555-5555,APPLE STORE,APPLE.COM,BUSINESS,456 peach ave,777-7777,PEACH STORE,PEACH.COM,BUSINESS,789 banana rd,999-9999,banana store,BUSINESS""") 
dfff.seek(0)
newdf2=pd.read_csv(dfff)
```

Here is the output, pandas renames the columns to have .1 or .2 for similar column names.

```
newdf2
#            address     phone         name    website      type      address.1   phone.1       name.1  website.1    type.1      address.2   phone.2        name.2    type.2
#0  123 APPLE STREET  555-5555  APPLE STORE  APPLE.COM  BUSINESS  456 peach ave  777-7777  PEACH STORE  PEACH.COM  BUSINESS  789 banana rd  999-9999  banana store  BUSINESS
```

How do I combine like address lines into seperate rows, to get this output ( since there is no website.2, it would be NaN or 0 or blank):

```
#            address     phone         name    website      type      
#0  123 APPLE STREET  555-5555  APPLE STORE  APPLE.COM  BUSINESS
#1     456 peach ave  777-7777  PEACH STORE  PEACH.COM  BUSINESS
#2     789 banana rd  999-9999  banana store       NaN  BUSINESS
```

Now, i don't really no where to start, but i tried to stack the data, that works as expected, but unstacking just brings back to the original data:

```
newdf2.stack().to_frame()
#                            0
#0 address    123 APPLE STREET
#  phone              555-5555
#  name            APPLE STORE
#  website           APPLE.COM
#  type               BUSINESS
#  address.1     456 peach ave
#  phone.1            777-7777
#  name.1          PEACH STORE
#  website.1         PEACH.COM
#  type.1             BUSINESS
#  address.2     789 banana rd
#  phone.2            999-9999
#  name.2         banana store
#  type.2             BUSINESS
```

I'm thinking there must be a way to stack, remove the .'s from the column, and unstack into the format i want? Or maybe there is another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use wide_to_long.

```
df.columns = [f'{x}.0' if '.' not in x else x for x in df.columns]
df['id'] = df.index

df = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['address', 'phone', 'name', 'website', 'type'], i='id', j='row', sep='.')

df.reset_index(drop=True)

Out[1]: 
            address     phone          name    website      type
0  123 APPLE STREET  555-5555   APPLE STORE  APPLE.COM  BUSINESS
1     456 peach ave  777-7777   PEACH STORE  PEACH.COM  BUSINESS
2     789 banana rd  999-9999  banana store        NaN  BUSINESS
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, i'll check this out. You wouldn't happen to know how to do the reverse as well? I'll ask that in a separate question actually

Comment: You might be interested in adding an answer here, since i think you might have the knowledge to get it ( mine is based on it ): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59022574/how-to-take-items-in-an-index-as-columns-in-pandas Mine is similar, in the question i linked, there are no .1, .2's in the data